# Translating wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to load my language files into the wordpress template. For this , I have created a folder called (languages) in the template root. Also I have generated the (*.po , *.mo) files for the language inside that directory.

I have added this code to the functions.php file :

```
    load_theme_textdomain( 'mytheme', TEMPLATEPATH.'/languages');

    $locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH."/languages/$locale.php";
    if ( is_readable($locale_file) )
    {
        require_once($locale_file); 
    }
```

The name of my language files are (ar.po,ar.mo). So I have tried using this line :

```
_e("home","mytheme");
```

but nothing replaced , the text still as the same. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but the language support must be enabled in `wp-config.php` too.

Example:

```
define('WPLANG', 'bg_BG');
define('WP_LANG_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wordpress/languages');
```

Copied from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Language_and_Language_Directory):

> WPLANG defines the name of the language translation (.mo) file.
>   WP_LANG_DIR defines what directory the WPLANG .mo file resides. If
>   WP_LANG_DIR is not defined WordPress looks first to
>   wp-content/languages and then wp-includes/languages for the .mo
>   defined by WPLANG file.